# How to get the name of a Service from a service project (maybe using DTE?)

Tags: c#, envdte

so i am using T4 templates to generate a script. one part i just came up against is getting the name of a service so that i can generate the sc.exe call to start the service.

I am getting to a lot of the info needed from the projects using DTE and can not find the service name. Any suggestions on how i can pull the service name programmatically??

I have been digging around the inter-web and cant seem to find anything on this topic. odds are i am just not searching for the right thing as i have never come across this particular hurdle before and am new to both DTE and T4 (awesome stuff though)